# asp.net mvc, returning multiple views as JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, view

Is it possible to return 2 separate views to an ajax call in Asp.net?

for example, if foo1 and foo2 are 2 ActionResult methods each returning a view?

```
return Json(new { a = foo1(), b = foo2() });
```

currently attempting this, the end result is that javascript gets it back as a class object rather then the actual view, anybody know how to get the resulting rendered html instead?

EDIT: I guess what I'm actually going for, is there a way for me to return the rendered view in string format?

Comment: `return Json` returns just that (`json`), not html. You need to return a partial view.

Comment: the json itself could contain the html in string form, which is what I'm hoping to get, sorry, guess I framed my question a bit incorrectly.

Comment: You have some code. What about it is not functioning as you expected? Show actual output and expected output.

Comment: the code works perfectly fine, I could bypass what I'm trying to do, but what I want to do is cut multiple ajax calls into a single call, currently fooi and foo2 would be grabbed in 2 calls to the server, and I want it to be a single call. that involves figuring our how to return multiple views as json

Comment: That appears to be what your code is doing now. Which is why I don't understand what you're asking for here.

Comment: but it's not, what I get is the actual ActionView object. returning as View("viewname") and partialview also does the same thing.

Comment: Unclear what you hoping to achieve with this. Since ajax is async, 2 calls will probably give you better performance anyway. If you want to return a view, then return a partial containing the 2 partials returned by `foo1()` and `foo2()`

Comment: You can convert a view to string and return your json as yourself mentioned. Take a look at this answer for converting a view to string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/692422

Answer (score 1):

Yes their is a way of returning view in `string` format.

For this you need to do following things:

1.You need some method in which you can pass your viewname along with object model. For this please refer below code and add to your helper class.

```
 public static class RenderViewLib
        {
            public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                    viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

                controller.ViewData.Model = model;
                using (var sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code will return your view in string format.

2.Now call above method from your json call like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        Mymodel model = new Mymodel();
        JsonResult jr = null;

        jr = Json(new
        {
            ViewHtml = this.RenderPartialView("_ViewName", model),
            ViewHtml2 = this.RenderPartialView("_ViewName2", model),
            IsSuccess = true
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return jr;
    }
```

and you will get your view as `string` format from your json call.

Hope this is what you are looking for.